# avoid duplicate path listing upto a certain subdirectory match in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, bazel

Team,
question is about coming up with bash approach to find path matching uniquely and avoid duplicates.

use case is to build bazel coverage only on changed paths.

I need to run bazel coverage only on paths where there is BUILD.bazel file underneath each unique path and there was a change under that path.

I am getting the paths of changed files from local git branch.

```
>git diff HEAD~1 --name-only | grep -e "src/" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'find $1 -type f -name BUILD.bazel' -- | awk -F 'BUILD.bazel' '{print $1}'

src/cmd
src/common
src/common/test1
src/common/test2
```

now, i want output to be as below and exclude dups under `../common/` because common will cover them anyways when I run bazel coverage `/src/common/...`

```
src/cmd
src/common
```

and finally i want to construct my bazel coverage like this which i will code later once i get above list.

```
bazel coverage //src/cmd //src/common
```

Answer (score 0):

OP: "*... now, i want output to be as below and exclude dups under ../common/ because common will cover them anyways when I run bazel coverage /src/common/...* "

- You can pipe your output into the below bash script, which should produce the reduced list.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PREV=""
while read -r line
do
if [[ "${PREV}" == "" ]]
then
        echo "$line"
        PREV="${line}"
else
        if [[ "${line#${PREV}}" == "${line}"  ]]
        then
            echo "${line}"
            PREV="${line}"
        fi
fi

done
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "src/cmd
src/common
src/common/test1
src/common/test2" \
| sort -t"/" -uk1,2 \
| xargs printf "//%s "
printf "\n"
```

Produces output:

```
//src/cmd //src/common
```

`-u` is uniq, `-k1,2` are the keys to sort and make uniq by.
You can probably change them to do "deeper" into a directory heirarchy and perform the same compacting, but it's likely you'll run into cases where you would need to run several differt key "sets" (1,2 .. 2,4 .. 3,4 ... what ever) to get the results you need for a more complicated issue.

You should e able to add this to the end of your existing pipeline and get the same results. I'm not able to test the exact code in my enviroment, so I'm using your current output as input.

Comment: thanks @shellter. this version `git diff HEAD~1 --name-only | grep -e "src/" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq | sort -t"/" -uk1,2 | xargs printf "//%s "` works fine but am not sure why is `printf "\n"` additional in end not inserting new line. it gives wierd output.

Comment: try commenting out the final `printf "\n"` and adding the `\n` to the `"//%s \n"` to see the difference. Good luck.